# interval of existence of solution of second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’m computing some exercises about the existence of solution of differenzial equation. But I don't really know how to do this one.
Determinate the maximum interval of existence of the solution of the following equation:
$$y''=y+y^2\qquad y(0)=0, \quad y'(0)=1$$
I'm sorry but my knowledge about differential equation is very poor, so any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: You can multiply with $2y'$ and integrate once. In the result you get $y'\sim y^{3/2}$ for $y$ large enough. This is sufficient for a singularity at a finite time.

Comment: Does it want the actual breakdown time? That seems hard to find. A bound is a lot easier to get.